# Recompile XAML (workflow) without re-opening file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

If I re-factor a type name, enum or constant that is relied upon within a workflow, the Visual Studio solution will compile without displaying any errors. However, if I re-open the workflow XAML, it is re-compiled and the appropriate error(s) displays in the error window.

I have 30+ workflows - this makes re-factoring somewhat difficult as I have to open and check for errors in each workflow before committing my work to source control.

Is there anyway to FORCE Visual Studio to re-compile all XAML files in the solution without opening them manually? (something similar to  property in MVC?

Regards

Warren

Answer (score 0):

XAML files aren't really compiled. Instead they are embedded as a resource and a wrapper type is generated that loads the XAML as a resource from the assembly. As a result errors in the XAML don't stop the project from compiling and only show up at runtime.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the added information, but the errors DO show up at design time when a dependency changes and the XAML file is opened in Visual Studio, therefore the IDE is somehow invoking up update without requiring run-time checking. Do you have a solution for manually invoking what the IDE is doing (either post-build event in the project, or instruction in the XAML file like MVC views allow)?

Comment: Back in October 2010 (pdc 10??) there was a WF4 futures presentation where they said workflow errors would break the build.  Was hoping this (and some other stuff) wouild show up in SP1, but no go.

Comment: @Warren: It's the WorkflowDesigner and its related services that are trapping the error and pushing into VS2010 so it can display it in the errors window. As Will mentioned this was supposed to be updated but not yet. There is still an .NET Framework Platform Update coming so a fix for this could be in there although I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: BTW For a start on the update look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg983472.aspx. The KB links are still dead though :-(

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I will keep an eye out for the update!